How to do different operations besides equals with Spring GraphQL, Spring Data, and QueryDSL
I'm trying to understand how Spring GraphQL handles more complex QueryDSL queries internally but I am struggling to find good documentation or examples of use cases such as doing range queries or like style searches. Does anyone have any example that shows how deep Spring GraphQL can go with QueryDSL?
I am currently able to get equals queries working just fine by tying the Entity objects to the GraphQL schema. It's the different operations that aren't very clear to me how to even begin to define them outside of a purely custom Repository method.
Just for reference, I'm reading the documentation here which states the following without clear guidance or example.
QuerydslDataFetcher supports customizing how GraphQL arguments are bound onto properties to create a Querydsl Predicate. By default, arguments are bound as "is equal to" for each available property. To customize that, you can use QuerydslDataFetcher builder methods to provide a QuerydslBinderCustomizer.
